# why is the icon moved away to top in ie6?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

why is the icon  moved away to top in ie6
it display ok in other browsers but not in ie6,what happened
how to fix this problem?
and can any one tell me how to write a better structure of my code showed on my demo?
demo : http://linjuming.pydra.org/leb/ie6_cw/index.html
[image]

Comment: IE 6??  Let it die.  Otherwise, make 100% sure your HTML is [100% valid](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Flinjuming.pydra.org%2Fleb%2Fie6_cw%2Findex.html&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) and hope for the best.  In other words, move `<style></style>` out of `<body></body>` and into `<head></head>` where it belongs.

Comment: You also have some other CSS issues.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `display: inline-block;` instead of `display: inline;`

```
.summary .grade_world {
    display: inline-block; <------- Here
    float: left;  <------ You don't need this
    background: url(grade_world.png) no-repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    height: 19px;
    width: 82px;
    position: relative; 
    top: 3px;
}
```

Comment: I don't see any other issue here, am not having IE6 for test, this was the best bet, anyways you can leave an unsupported browser message, IE6 is dead now

Comment: Did you try moving `style` tags out of `body` and into `head`?

Comment: @Sparky672 I don't think that solves, It's not JavaScript, styles are fine if you place it anywhere on the page...

Comment: It may not solve anything, but it's certainly invalid HTML and IE handles invalid HTML very poorly.